# Comparing two objects through serialization

Tags: java

Will comparing two objects of the same class by converting both of them into json strings / serialize them into bytes always work? Is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: The biggest problem is that a JSON "object" does not guarantee the order of the key/value pairs, so two "identical" JSON "objects" could have the same key/value pairs in different orders.

Comment: One could, in theory, use a "deep equals" on the JSON tree representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is probably not a good idea.  What makes objects "equal" depends on the object.  Comparing every field for equality may not be the correct test.

Further, the ordering of fields in JSON is not guaranteed, and I am not sure if the order of fields in the binary serialization format are guaranteed either.  The serializer deciding in some cases to emit the fields in a different order could result in false negatives.